# How to fix issue with bootstrap angular 6

Tags: angular

So Im currently following along with a tutorial about angular 6 but it seems as though I'm having a problem with the bootstrap. Whenever i try running the program in visual studio code's terminal, i always end up with the errors

```
 ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\zach\College\Spring 2019\Senior Proj\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css' in 'C:\Users\zach\College\Spring 2019\Senior Proj\Wholesale-cli'
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

Is the the bootstrap not being found in a specified area?

Comment: It looks more like a compatibility issue than problems with Bootstrap itself. Try updating your typescript to a newer version and see if it solves.

Comment: Are you using vanilla Bootstrap, or one of the Angular specific libraries? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home or https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/